# Storing a constant in SSE register (GCC, C++)

Tags: c++, c, assembly, sse, inline-assembly

Hello StackOverflow community

I have encountered a following challenge: In my C++ application I have quite complex (cubic) loop in which, at all depths, I perform the following:

1. Compute 4 float values
2. Multiply all 4 values by a constant
3. Convert the floats to integers

This code is to be run with thousands of iterations in each loop (resulting in billions of operations) and I want to make it as fast as possible, so I'm trying to utilize SSE processor instructions.

While trying to manually optimize the code, I have encountered the following obstacle: each time I get to the part with multiplying all values by a constant, the constant has to be loaded to XMM register. My idea was to reserve one register (and forbid the compiler from using it), load the value once, and hardcode the multiplications with that one specific register, however I can't find the right way to do that.

By the way, could somebody please explain to me, why does this code:

```
    vmovaps .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    movl    $1000000000, %eax
    vmovaps .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
#APP
# 26 "sse.cpp" 1
    .intel_syntax noprefix;
    mulps %xmm1,%xmm0;
    .att_syntax prefix;

# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    subl    $1, %eax
    jne     .L2
```

Performs worse (real    0m1.656s vs real    0m1.618s) than the following one:

```
    vmovaps .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    movl    $1000000000, %eax
    vmovaps .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm1
    subl    $1, %eax
    jne     .L2
```

(The difference is that I use intel syntax in my inline asm in gcc [first snippet] and legacy SSE instructions for compatibility, while gcc automatically generated version using AVX vectors [second snippet])

Comment: You should use builtin vector support and/or intrinsics. Also, if you want to use intel syntax compile with -masm=intel and don't try to hack around the back of the compiler. As for reserving a register, that's probably a bad idea too, but gcc allows global register variables.

Comment: Umm doesn't declaring a `const __mm128` variable as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9080351/1133179 help?

Comment: @Jester -masm=intel breaks some boost dependencies, tried that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One note, you need to be more specific on how you do compile things and probably provide minimal example. I know it might not be best answer because of this, but I think it's good enough. It got long but it's because of codes.

**Bottom line of below work is that it should be safe to leave for the compiler and use appropriate compiler flags.** At the bottom I put an example how to use local register variable, but it probably won't be very useful (it gets ignored easily). You could use global register variable but it doesn't yield any good results and is discouraged.

My set-up is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU`, `gcc version 4.9.2` and `clang version 3.5.0`. Below code does store `avx_scalar` in an `xmm` register with `-O1` and above. With nothing or `-O0` they don't. The code to generate assembly was:

`[clang++|g++] -march=native -S -Ox ./sse.cpp`,

where `x` was the optimization level.

Interesting thing is that with `-march=archive` both compilers decided to use SSE4.1 versions over legacy SSE in any case I tested, even though I used legacy SSE intrinsics in the code itself. This is good.

I also tested using `smmintrin.h` which is SSE4.1 header. With out the flag gcc uses legacy SSE and clang fails to compile with `error: "SSE4.1 instruction set not enabled"`. With `xmmintrin.h` which is legacy SSE header, both compilers produced AVX versions in the presence of the flag, and legacy ones when it was absent.

Test code `avx.cpp`:

```
extern "C" 
{
#include <smmintrin.h>
}

const float scalar = 3.14;
const __m128 avx_scalar = _mm_set1_ps(scalar);
__m128 vector;

__m128 its_me(){
    __m128 ret;
    __m128 result;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        vector = _mm_set_ps(i*1,i*2,i*3,i*4);
        result = _mm_mul_ps(vector, avx_scalar);
        ret = _mm_add_ps(ret, result);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Revelvant part of `g++ -march=native -S -O2 ./avx.cpp`:

```
.LFB639:
        .cfi_startproc
        vmovaps _ZL10avx_scalar(%rip), %xmm5
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L2:
        leal    (%rdx,%rdx), %ecx
        vxorps  %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vxorps  %xmm1, %xmm1, %xmm1
        vxorps  %xmm3, %xmm3, %xmm3
        leal    0(,%rdx,4), %eax
        vcvtsi2ss       %ecx, %xmm3, %xmm3
        vxorps  %xmm4, %xmm4, %xmm4
        vcvtsi2ss       %eax, %xmm2, %xmm2
        leal    (%rcx,%rdx), %eax
        vcvtsi2ss       %edx, %xmm4, %xmm4
        addl    $1, %edx
        vcvtsi2ss       %eax, %xmm1, %xmm1
        vunpcklps       %xmm4, %xmm3, %xmm3
        vunpcklps       %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm1
        vmovlhps        %xmm3, %xmm1, %xmm1
        vmulps  %xmm5, %xmm1, %xmm2
        vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm0, %xmm0
        cmpl    $1000, %edx
        jne     .L2
        vmovaps %xmm1, vector(%rip)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

And `clang++ -march=native -S -O2 ./avx.cpp`:

```
# BB#0:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    $4, %ecx
        movl    $2, %edx
        vmovaps _ZL10avx_scalar(%rip), %xmm1
        xorl    %esi, %esi
                                        # implicit-def: XMM0
        .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        leal    -2(%rdx), %r8d
        leal    -4(%rcx), %edi
        vmovd   %edi, %xmm2
        vpinsrd $1, %eax, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vpinsrd $2, %r8d, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vpinsrd $3, %esi, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vcvtdq2ps       %xmm2, %xmm2
        vmulps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm0, %xmm0
        leal    1(%rsi), %r8d
        leal    3(%rax), %edi
        vmovd   %ecx, %xmm2
        vpinsrd $1, %edi, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vpinsrd $2, %edx, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vpinsrd $3, %r8d, %xmm2, %xmm2
        vcvtdq2ps       %xmm2, %xmm2
        vmulps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm3
        vaddps  %xmm3, %xmm0, %xmm0
        addl    $2, %esi
        addl    $6, %eax
        addl    $8, %ecx
        addl    $4, %edx
        cmpl    $1000, %esi             # imm = 0x3E8
        jne     .LBB0_1
# BB#2:
        vmovaps %xmm2, vector(%rip)
        retq
```

**Just for the record**, you can manually put a local variable into register, but clang ignores completely and gcc with `-01` and above.I encourage to look for `xmm13` in output from `g++ -march=native -S -Ox ./avx.cpp` with different `x` values for the below code (assuming you have at least 13 xmm registers on your cpu):

```
extern "C" 
{
#include <xmmintrin.h>
}

const float scalar = 3.14;

__m128 its_me(){
    __m128 vector;
    register __m128 avx_scalar asm ("xmm13") = _mm_set1_ps(scalar); // that's how you do it in gcc.
    //const __m128 avx_scalar = _mm_set1_ps(scalar);
    __m128 ret;
    __m128 result;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        vector = _mm_set_ps(i*1,i*2,i*3,i*4);
            result = _mm_mul_ps(vector, avx_scalar);
        ret = _mm_add_ps(ret, result);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `_mm_set_ps` inside an inner loop if you can avoid it.  Set `{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }` once, then `_mm_add_ps` a vector of `{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}` to generate `vector`.  That will replace 4 integer adds, `vmovd`, 3x `vpinsrd`, and a `vcvtdq2ps` with a `vaddps` in the loop.  Or if you really need to avoid any possible rounding-error accumulation, add to a vector of integers, so you just have a `vpaddd` and `vcvtdq2ps` in the inner loop.

Comment: That's a good analysis, albeit pretty useless for the answer. `__mm_set_ps` is just to emulate the "*Compute 4 float values*" it can be slow, and it's not a real implementation. I don't really see a point of optimizing something made up. Still I find it an interesting observation and advice from the micro-optimization perspective. It certainly has its value.

Comment: I think I didn't read the text outside of the code carefully enough to pick up on `mm_set_ps` on the loop counter being a placeholder.  Actually, I seem to remember wondering about that, but it had a big impact on the generated code, so I posted anyway.  >.<